# Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::paginate does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, function, pagination, controller

I have this code:

```
$transactions = DB::table('transactions')
        ->join('orders', 'transactions.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
        ->get()->paginate(5);


return view('transactions.index', ['transactions' => $transactions]);
```

the code result in this error:

> Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::paginate does not exist

Comment: I'm not sure but just try to remove get() method and use paginate(5) only. Hope it will help you. Because there was some return type issue.

Comment: `->get()` returns collection while `->paginate()` asks for query builder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following query

```
 $transactions = DB::table('transactions')->join('orders', 'transactions.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')->paginate(5);
```

remove get() from query

Comment: still having  error not showing Pagination

Comment: can you explain more what error now you facing?

Answer (score 2):

Laravel collection deosn't support pagination, but db query does, so you have to tell your query to paginate not the collection:

```
$transactions = DB::table('transactions')
        ->join('orders', 'transactions.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')->paginate(5);
```

Comment: still having the same problem, not showing Pagination

Answer (score 0):

you can not use `paginate` after `get` method, use the below code

```
$transactions = DB::table('transactions')
    ->join('orders', 'transactions.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
    ->paginate(5);
return view('transactions.index', ['transactions' => $transactions]);
```

Comment: still having  same problem, not showing Pagination

Comment: did you call ``links()`` in your view file?